# SQLServer difference between new login and new database user

Tags: sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between a User and a Login in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134319/difference-between-a-user-and-a-login-in-sql-server)

Is it enough to create a database login with permission to desired database? Or do I need to create a database user for this login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A login is a login account for the entire SQL Server instance - an instance can contain numerous databases.

A user is defined at the database level, and is associated with a login to provide interactive access (privileges providing)

Logins are a server side (instance level) objects. Their correct name is 'server principals' (see sys.server_principals). Server wide privileges are granted to logins, like create database or view server state permissions.

Users are a database objects, correctly referred to as 'database principals' (see sys.database_principals). They are the recipients of database permissions, like create table or select.

Ordinarily a login is mapped 1-to-1 to a user in each database, via a matching SID, but there are some exception, like all members of the sysadmin fixed server role are always mapped to dbo.

Users without login are a specific construct for Service Broker remote identities (see Remote Service Bindings) and for code signing. You should never have to create one in any other context, and if you do, you're likely doing it wrong. Users without login are never meant to be impersonated.

Comment: Dear Asif,  I created a new login and assigned a database to this login. Now when I expand that database and check under users, this login is already listed there. So what is the point of creating a new database user associated with this login and how to implement this?

Comment: What i got from your comments is that you are creating a new database and mapping the already created login with that user.
Simply go into Security Section -> Logins -> open properties of User  -> User Mapping -> give rights to desired database.