# Fail to login with this user "xxx" SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL it shows me an error message.
I got error while log in to SQL with USER **sa** & Password.
Also I have reset the password from the **Logins** security.
I have checked lot of links but unable to log in.
How can I rectify this issue?
I have used following links-
[itproguru](http://itproguru.com/expert/2014/09/how-to-fix-login-failed-for-user-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-step-by-step-add-sql-administrator-to-sql-management-studio/), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667670/unable-to-log-in-to-server-in-sql-server-2008-r2-management-studio)

Comment: Where is the error? can you poste the error message please?

Comment: What are you trying to log into SQL Server with? Your own application? Where's the code for that?