# SQL Server equivalent of Oracle USER

Tags: sql-server, oracle

While converting an Oracle code block I found this:

```
IF :NEW.username != USER THEN
```

Now, my question - what exactly is `USER` in Oracle? In SQL Server I have:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.server_principals
```

Is the 'name' here same as Oracle `USER`?

Comment: `USER` in oracle is the user is current connected

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL Server`, the `NAME` in `sys.database_principals` is the `USER`. There was a similar question in dbastackexchange here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22803/listing-the-existing-sql-server-logins-and-users

In Oracle, `USER` is an account through which you can log in to the database, and to establish the means by which Oracle Database permits access by the user.

For example, I connected to the sample schema "SCOTT", I connect like :

`conn scott/tiger@database`

So, here the user is "SCOTT". Let's see :

```
SQL> show user;
USER is "SCOTT"
```

Comment: Thanks for this . So , in that case I think Oracle `USER'` is equivalent to SQL SERVER `SUSER_SNAME()` . Please comment if any of you think I am not correct .

Comment: No. It returns the login name, while a user and login name are not similar in SQL Server. One "Login" can be associated with many users (one per database). Have a look at similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134319/difference-between-a-user-and-a-login-in-sql-server