# Creating a user in SQL Server and using that user in web.config file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, web-config, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create a user in SQL Server. I can create the user fine and then I grant that user some privileges. Here is the code:

```
CREATE LOGIN TestLogin WITH password='abc';

 -- Now add user to database
USE TestDB;
CREATE USER TestUser FOR LOGIN TestLogin;
GO

use [TestDB]
GO
GRANT INSERT TO [TestUser]
GO
use [TestDB]
GO
GRANT SELECT TO [TestUser]
GO
use [TestDB]
GO
GRANT UPDATE TO [TestUser]
GO
use [TestDB]
GO
DENY DELETE TO [TestUser]
GO
```

After this I want to use this user in my web.config file.

```
<add name="DBConnectionString"
     connectionString="Server=tcp:abc.database.windows.net;Database=TestDB;User ID=TestLogin;Password=abc;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My question is: in the `web.config` file I have to use the LOGIN user. When I apply migrations, I don't want to run any DELETE statements so I created a USER and denied him the access. Can I use this user in the `web.config` file?

My goal is that when migrations are applied I don't want to execute DELETE. Will my approach work or what should I change?

Comment: if your migration scripts include delete statements,they will fail.other than that i dont see any issue.You may also encrypt password in webconfig file if you think others might get azure password

Comment: What if I have multiple users for my db "TestDB" and each user has different privileges?

Comment: I don't follow your concern about having multiple users- your connection string is defined to use a specific user within web.config; other users having different privileges are irrelevant to `TestLogin`'s privileges.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm granting privileges to `TestUser` and not `TestLogin`. Sorry if it's a bit confusing.

Comment: My apologies- I missed that salient detail; You created a server level principal (the Login), and then created a database level principal (the user); if you aren't familiar with the difference, [here was a question on that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134319/difference-between-a-user-and-a-login-in-sql-server). 
In your example, you mapped `TestLogin` -> `TestUser` on `TestDB`
`TestLogin` will have the permission level you assigned to `TestUser` since you're connecting to `TestDB`.

Comment: Alright thanks, so when I apply a migration that includes DELETE statements, the migration shouldn't succeed right?

Comment: it  depends ,if all are wrapped in a transaction,then it will fail

Comment: I believe it's best practice to avoid chaining questions in comments. I'm moving my explanation to an answer as well, since I believe it covers your first question fully.

Comment: You seem to be concerned with something that isn't limited to permissions, but rather with the operations within what you're calling "migrations". What do you mean by "migrations"?

Comment: @drediske. I was wanted to know what would happen if DB migrations were applied with restrictions on the DB. But I tested it, and it seems that the migration will fail if it tries to execute something that there is a restriction on.

Answer (score 1):

You created a server level principal (the Login), and then created a database level principal (the user) and modified it's permissions; if you aren't familiar with the difference, [here was a question on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134319/difference-between-a-user-and-a-login-in-sql-server).

In your example, you mapped `TestLogin` -> `TestUser` on `TestDB`; this means that `TestLogin` will have the permission level you assigned to `TestUser` since you're connecting to `TestDB`. (So YES you will have denied DELETE to the connection defined in the connection string.)

As for your question in the comments about your migration- when executed via this connection string, as far as my understanding goes, it should fail.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.